# bottom tab slider xamarin android

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android

I have a problem adding items and events to the tab_slide_bottom.

main project url

[enter link description here](https://intelliabb.com/2017/12/02/tutorial-bottomnavigationview-and-viewpager-in-xamarin-android/)

my full code

[enter link description here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/13p0GcPh4oIFZsY_mht1YwM7RXSVB3l96/view?usp=sharing)

**TheFragmentLayout,imageView1**

```
   public override View OnCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            var view = inflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.TheFragmentLayout, container, false);
            var imageView = view.FindViewById<ImageView>(Resource.Id.imageView1);

            int resID = (int)typeof(Resource.Drawable).GetField(_icon).GetValue(null);
            imageView.SetImageResource(resID);

            var textView = view.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.Title);
            textView.SetText(_title, null);

            return view;
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please open your `TheFragment.cs` file, you NameSpace is `BottomNavigationViewPager` ,please change it to your project namespace `tab_slide_bottom`

```
namespace tab_slide_bottom.Fragments
{
    public class TheFragment : Fragment
    {
        string _title;
        string _icon;

        public static TheFragment NewInstance(string title, string icon)
        {
            var fragment = new TheFragment();
            fragment.Arguments = new Bundle();
            fragment.Arguments.PutString("title", title);
            fragment.Arguments.PutString("icon", icon);
            return fragment;
        }

        public override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

            if (Arguments != null)
            {
                if (Arguments.ContainsKey("title"))
                    _title = (string)Arguments.Get("title");

                if (Arguments.ContainsKey("icon"))
                    _icon = (string)Arguments.Get("icon");
            }
        }

        public override View OnCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
           // res
            var view = inflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.fragment_layout, container, false);
            var imageView = view.FindViewById<ImageView>(Resource.Id.imageView1);

            int resID = (int)typeof(Resource.Drawable).GetField(_icon).GetValue(null);
            imageView.SetImageResource(resID);

            var textView = view.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.my_title);
            textView.SetText(_title, null);

            return view;
        }
    }
}
```

Here is your code running GIF.

[image]

Here is your project, you can download it.

https://github.com/851265601/Xamarin.Android_ListviewSelect/blob/master/tab_slide_bottom.zip

Comment: If the reply is helpful, please do not forget to mark it as answer, it will help others who have similar issue.

Comment: hi  Leon Lu ,Thanks for answering my question